# shapefile not showing up in results after running a customized model

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder

I made a custom model containing two buffers and one erase to show the area within 2 miles, but 0.5 miles away from major roads. The model runs perfectly, but there isn't any result produced. The shapefile for both buffers are available in the catalog but the shapefile that should be produced by the final erase function is not there and could not be found in the folder either. Here is my model.

[image]

Comment: Are you running this through the model editor (with it open) or just by double clicking it in a toolbox? Is the final output marked as intermediate (right click on it)?

Comment: It was one of my previously finished model and I modified it for the new purpose. Would you explain why I need to change the final output to intermediate as well? I thought only those in the middle should be intermediate so that they won't show up in the result.

Comment: And the while model is running amazingly slow. I'm using an 8GB RAM, i7-4770 CPU desktop and I don't even know how long is takes because I have to keep it running for the whole night. I estimate it to be longer than two hours. The shapefile I'm working with is only couple of MB.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to verify that it is not intermediate, ArcGIS will delete it after the model is complete if it is.

Comment: It has been working for over four hours now and still at the 7th step out of 16 in total. What do you think is wrong with it? Thank you.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using?